# Is it possible to block an embedded object's (Flash) popup with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, flash

In case I wanted to use an embedded SWF object (remotely hosted) but not have it do random unpredictable things... like popups to other sites.

Comment: place above it a transparent div of the same size :D

Comment: No.  The above suggestion would block any clicks, but if it's just part of the actionscript to open a popup then you can't do anything about that with jQuery.